# Safely insert or update subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, atomic

I have a MongoDB where I keep record of Items with arrays of SubItems. When adding or updating SubItems, I first `Find` the main `Item`, then I add the new `SubItem` to the array of `SubItems` and replace the entire `Item`. This worked "great" until I started batch inserting `SubItems`.

I think my problem is that the find and update are not one atomic operation and the result is that I'm losing `SubItems`.

I'm using the .NET MongoDB.Driver and my save method looks like this:

```
public Task Save(string itemId, SubItem subItem)
{
    var itemFilter = Builders<Item>.Filter.Eq(v => v.Id, itemId);
    var collection = _db.GetCollection<Item>("Items");

    var item = await collection.Find(itemFilter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    item.SubItems.Add(subItem);
    collection.ReplaceOneAsync(itemFilter, item, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true }).Wait();
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Here is my data model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to insert or update a `SubItem` in one operation so I can ensure I keep the entire `Item` document consistent even if I have multiple processes trying to update the document at the same time?

Comment: "upserts" and arrays generally don't tend to mix very well. The typical case is to "test" with multiple operations ( typically in bulk ) for the presence of the item in the array and then either "push" the new item or "update" where it exists. You can "somewhat" simplify the case with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) "if" the array content is simply values or a "single" property. If there is more than one property however, "uniqueness" means the combination of those properties in that context and it falls back to the "test" approach instead.

Comment: The "upsert" problem is when any such update requires "testing" the presence of an element within an array, "any" negative result means an "upsert" always occurs when your actual intent may have been to "append" the array of the existing document rather than a new one. So the actual process you employ really depends on your intended pattern. If you truly want "upserts" and you want multiple properties in the array, then you actually mean to do "multiple operations" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [AddToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) method, if you use this in combination with the update function instead of the replace one it should keep a better control of your atomicity.

```
var updateBuilder = Builders<Item>.Update.AddToSet(items => items.SubItems, new SubItem());

collection.UpdateOne(itemFilter, updateBuilder);
```

Like so in your case.

```
    public Task Save(string itemId, SubItem subItem)
    {
        var itemFilter = Builders<Item>.Filter.Eq(v => v.Id, itemId);
        var collection = _db.GetCollection<Item>("Items");

        var updateBuilder = Builders<Item>.Update.AddToSet(items => items.SubItems, subItem);

        collection.UpdateOneAsync(itemFilter, updateBuilder, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true }).Wait();
    }
```

Comment: What if subitem have more than one properties? how does mongodb "knows" how to update the correct subitem?