# Mongo UpdateOne for adding a subdocument to array C# using Lambda and FieldDefinition

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am having a problem with field definition with c# mongo driver. My Robo 3T updateOne works just fine, so clearly I understand the mongo side of things.

In essence I need to create a field definition I can use in an updateOn() operation: `FieldDefinition<Team>` however I should explain what im trying to do which leads to this issue. That way maybe there is a different and more appropriate solution.

The following mongo query works just fine in Robo 3T

```
db.teams.update({
    _id: ObjectId("607ff1fb313a448aa3312272")
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        Users:         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("603cd341e420290239a2baf0"),
            "id" : 94,
            "first_name" : "Jane",
            "surname" : "Darling",

        }
    }
});
```

Having proved my understanding I went on to create the following C# code to do this.

```
            UpdateDefinition<Team> UpdateDefinition 
                = Builders<Team>.Update.
                    AddToSet(x => x.TeamMembers, UserList);
          
            MongoClient.UpdateOne<Team>(
                TeamFilter, 
                UpdateDefinition, 
                CollectionTeam);
```

If you look at the following post it looks like my assumption is correct on how to specify the array to insert the sub document into:
[Safely insert or update subdocument in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269453/safely-insert-or-update-subdocument-in-mongodb)

However I get the following error:
[image]

This is okay with me too, so I tried to create a field definition and I am presently stuck. In theory creating a FieldDefinition should be easy. Except im not finding suitable examples.

In essence this is the method signature im trying to make use of
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple

```
            UpdateDefinition<Team> UpdateDefinition
                = Builders<Team>.Update.
                    AddToSetEach(x => x.TeamMembers, UserList);
```

The reason it's not easy to find is this that the mongo driver syntax isn't the same as the mongo syntax.